# how to shorten arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

```
import SpriteKit



struct Square {
var node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SquareTile")
var position = CGPoint()
var startColor = UIColor()
var secondColor = UIColor()
var targetColor = UIColor()
var permanent = Bool()
var has3Colors = Bool()
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

var alive = Bool()
var targetColors = Array<UIColor>()
var permanent = Array<Bool>()
var has3Colors = Array<Bool>()
var secondColors = Array<UIColor>()
var positions = Array<CGPoint>()
var startColors = Array<UIColor>()
var circle = SKSpriteNode()
var completedSquares = Int()
var started = Bool()
var squares = Array<Square>()

var basicSize = CGSize()

var row1 = CGFloat()
var row2 = CGFloat()
var row3 = CGFloat()
var row4 = CGFloat()
var row5 = CGFloat()
var targetColor = UIColor()
var isPermanent = Bool()
var hasThreeColors = Bool()
var secondColor = UIColor()
var position1 = CGPoint()
var startColor = UIColor()
var square = SKSpriteNode()
var columbs = Array<CGFloat>()
var rows = Array<CGFloat>()





override func didMove(to view: SKView) {



}



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {



    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if started == false{
            started = true


            start()
            for i in 0 ... 24{





            }
                  squares.forEach { self.addChild($0.node) }

        }


        circle.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))

    }
}




 func start(){

    basicSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 7, height: self.frame.width / 7)

    createCircle()
    getArrays()


}
func getArrays(){
rowsAndColumbs()

    var squares = (0...24).map { _ in Square() }
    for square in squares{

    square.node.position = square.position
    square.node.color = square.startColor

    }

    for i in (0...24){



        squares[i].startColor = startColors[i]
        squares[i].has3Colors = has3Colors[i]
        squares[i].secondColor = secondColors[i]
        squares[i].targetColor = targetColors[i]
        squares[i].permanent = permanent[i]
        squares[i].position = positions[i]


    }




    for columb in columbs{
        for row in rows{
            positions.append(CGPoint(x: columb, y: row))


        }
    }


    loadLvl1()

}
func loadLvl1(){

    var targetColors1 = Array<UIColor>()
    var permanent1 = Array<Bool>()
    var has3Colors1 = Array<Bool>()
    var secondColors1 = Array<UIColor>()
    var startColors1 = Array<UIColor>()

    targetColors1 = [.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green]
    permanent1 = [true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true]
    secondColors1 = [.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear]
    has3Colors1 = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
    startColors1 = [.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue]

    var lvl1Array = Array<Array<Any>>()
    lvl1Array = [targetColors1,permanent1,has3Colors1,secondColors1,startColors1]

    targetColors = lvl1Array[0] as! Array<UIColor>
    permanent = lvl1Array[1] as! Array<Bool>
    has3Colors = lvl1Array[2] as! Array<Bool>
    secondColors = lvl1Array[3] as! Array<UIColor>
    startColors = lvl1Array[4] as! Array<UIColor>





}
func rowsAndColumbs(){

columbs = (1...5).map {basicSize.width * (CGFloat($0) + 0.5)}
rows = (1...5).map {basicSize.height * (CGFloat($0) + 0.5)}




}
func createCircle(){

    circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
    circle.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 7, height: self.frame.width / 7)
    circle .position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
    self.addChild(circle)

}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {}
    // Called before each frame is rendered

}
```

This is my project and i am using arrays to make a grid but i keep getting a lot of errors like Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) and i think they are a lot about how i made my arrays. I made some of them like [false, false, true, false, false, true, false] is there a way to shorten them or make them in a way better that that so that they won't be so big and long and make  so many errors or any other ways to shorten my project?

Comment: your question better fit to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes you are right - it make no sense so much arrays floating around and global / class vars.

Comment: you should have a GameBoard struct where are the squares are sitting. and you should save your game level better as json for example. and each json subnode should have all the needed properties. then you just read the json when you load a level

Comment: maybe you will add later a LevelEditor? why not write this first and save the GameLevel as JSON - then you dont need this big values lines

Comment: @muescha i have no experience with that could you recommend me a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i played a little with your code in Playground.

i implemented a `GameConfig` where i saved most game setting
i created a struct `Square` to save there all relevant informations about a square
i all levels comes from a `LevelRepository` (a `MemoryLevelRepository` or a `JsonFileLevelRepository`) feel free to implement other Repositories (for example from your server)
and i implemented an `DimensionsCalculator` to change fast the layout

main idea to avoid to many class variables to encapsulate all in classes (for example the `LevelRepository`)

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport


// GameConfig Structure

struct GameConfig {
    var frame: CGRect
    var itemTopLeft: CGPoint
    var itemSize: CGSize
    var itemSpacing: CGSize
    var circleSize: CGSize
    var circlePosition: CGPoint
    var backgroundColor: UIColor
    var itemsPerLine: Int
    var currentLevel: Int
}


// Square Structure

struct Square {
    var position: CGPoint
    var size: CGSize
    var startColor: UIColor
    var secondColor: UIColor
    var targetColor: UIColor
    var permanent: Bool
    var has3Colors: Bool
}

extension Square {
    func node() -> SKSpriteNode{

         let node = SKSpriteNode(
                color: self.startColor
                ,size: self.size
            )
        node.position = self.position
        return node
    }
}


// DimensionsCalculator

protocol DimensionsCalculator {


    func positionFromIndex(_ index: Int) -> CGPoint
    func sizeFromIndex(_ index: Int) -> CGSize
}

class LinearDimensionsCalculator: DimensionsCalculator {

    var gameConfig: GameConfig

    init(gameConfig: GameConfig){
        self.gameConfig = gameConfig
    }

    func positionFromIndex(_ index: Int) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: 130, y: index * 5 + 100)
    }

    func sizeFromIndex(_ index: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: index*3 + 10, height: 3 )
    }
}

class BoardDimensionsCalculator: DimensionsCalculator {

    var gameConfig: GameConfig

    init(gameConfig: GameConfig){
        self.gameConfig = gameConfig
    }

    func positionFromIndex(_ index: Int) -> CGPoint {
        let gridSizeX = Int(gameConfig.itemSize.width + gameConfig.itemSpacing.width)
        let gridSizeY = Int(gameConfig.itemSize.width + gameConfig.itemSpacing.width)
        let x: Int = (index % gameConfig.itemsPerLine) * gridSizeX + Int(gameConfig.itemTopLeft.x)
        let y: Int = (index / gameConfig.itemsPerLine) * -gridSizeY + Int(gameConfig.itemTopLeft.y)
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }

    func sizeFromIndex(_ index: Int) -> CGSize {
        return gameConfig.itemSize
    }

}


// GameScene

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var circle: SKSpriteNode?
    var gameConfig: GameConfig

    init(gameConfig: GameConfig) {
        self.gameConfig = gameConfig
        super.init(size: gameConfig.frame.size)
        self.backgroundColor = gameConfig.backgroundColor
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        start()
        super.didMove(to: view)
    }

    func start(){
        createSquares()
        createCircle()
    }

    func createSquares(){

//        let pc = LinearDimensionsCalculator(gameConfig: gameConfig)
        let pc = BoardDimensionsCalculator(gameConfig: gameConfig)

        let levelRepository = MemoryLevelRepository(dimensionsCalculator: pc  as DimensionsCalculator)

        let squares = levelRepository.loadLevel(gameConfig.currentLevel)

        squares.forEach{ square in
           addChild(square.node())
        }
    }

    func createCircle(){
        let size = gameConfig.circleSize
        circle = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blue, size: size)
        circle?.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: gameConfig.circlePosition.y)
        self.addChild(circle!)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            circle?.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))
        }

    }

}

protocol LevelRepository {
    func loadLevel(_ level: Int) -> [Square]
    func levelCount() -> Int
}

class JsonFileLevelRepository: LevelRepository{

    var dimensionsCalculator: DimensionsCalculator

    init(dimensionsCalculator: DimensionsCalculator){
        self.dimensionsCalculator = dimensionsCalculator
    }

    func loadLevel(_ level: Int) -> [Square]{
        let jsonFile = "Level_\(level)"
        let path = "xxx" + jsonFile
        return parseFile(fileName: path)
    }

    func parseFile(fileName: String) -> [Square]{
        let squares = [Square]()
        // parse here an jsonfile
        return squares
    }

    func levelCount() -> Int {
        let levelCount = 10 // Count the files in directory
        return levelCount
    }
}

class MemoryLevelRepository: LevelRepository{

    var dimensionsCalculator: DimensionsCalculator

    init(dimensionsCalculator: DimensionsCalculator){
        self.dimensionsCalculator = dimensionsCalculator
    }

    func levelCount() -> Int {
        let levelCount = 2 // Level0 and Level1
        return levelCount
    }

    func loadLevel(_ level: Int) -> [Square]{
        switch level {
        case 0:
            return loadLevel0()
        case 1:
            return loadLevel1()
        default:
            return loadLevel0()
        }

    }

    func loadLevel0() -> [Square] {
        return [
            Square(
                position: CGPoint.zero,
                size:CGSize.zero,
                startColor: .green,
                secondColor: .red,
                targetColor: .blue,
                permanent: true,
                has3Colors: true
            ),
            Square(
                position: CGPoint.zero,
                size:CGSize.zero,
                startColor: .green,
                secondColor: .red,
                targetColor: .red,
                permanent: true,
                has3Colors: true
            ),
            Square(
                position: CGPoint.zero,
                size:CGSize.zero,
                startColor: .green,
                secondColor: .red,
                targetColor: .brown,
                permanent: true,
                has3Colors: true
            ),
            Square(
                position: CGPoint.zero,
                size:CGSize.zero,
                startColor: .green,
                secondColor: .red,
                targetColor: .green,
                permanent: true,
                has3Colors: true
            )
            ]
            .enumerated()
            .map{ index, square in
                // apply size and position
                var square = square
                square.position = dimensionsCalculator.positionFromIndex(index)
                square.size = dimensionsCalculator.sizeFromIndex(index)
                return square
            }

    }

    func loadLevel1() -> [Square]{
        var squares = [Square]()

            var startColors1: [UIColor] = [
                 .green,.gray,.blue,.blue,.green
                ,.green,.green,.green,.green,.green
                ,.green,.black,.green,.green,.blue
                ,.green,.green,.red,.green,.green
                ,.brown,.green,.green,.green,.blue]

            var permanent1: [Bool] = [
                 true,true,true,true,true
                ,true,true,true,true,true
                ,true,true,true,true,true
                ,true,true,true,true,true
                ,true,true,true,true,true]

            var targetColors1: [UIColor] = [
                 .clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear
                ,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear
                ,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear
                ,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear
                ,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear,.clear]

            var has3Colors1: [Bool] = [
                 false,false,false,false,false
                ,false,false,false,false,false
                ,false,false,false,false,false
                ,false,false,false,false,false
                ,false,false,false,false,false]

            var secondColors1: [UIColor] = [
                 .blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue
                ,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue
                ,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue
                ,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue
                ,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue,.blue]


//        print(targetColors1.count)
//        print(permanent1.count)
//        print(startColors1.count)
//        print(has3Colors1.count)
//        print(secondColors1.count)

        squares = (0..<targetColors1.count).map{

            Square(
                position: dimensionsCalculator.positionFromIndex($0),
                size: dimensionsCalculator.sizeFromIndex($0),
                startColor: startColors1[$0],
                secondColor: secondColors1[$0],
                targetColor: targetColors1[$0],
                permanent: permanent1[$0],
                has3Colors: has3Colors1[$0]
            )
        }
        return squares
    }
}

let boardFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)
var basicSize = CGSize(width: boardFrame.width / 7, height: boardFrame.width / 7)

var gameConfigSmall = GameConfig(
    frame: boardFrame,
    itemTopLeft: CGPoint(x: 100, y:200),
    itemSize: CGSize.init(width: 15, height: 15),
    itemSpacing: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10),
    circleSize: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5),
    circlePosition: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10),
    backgroundColor: UIColor.lightGray,
    itemsPerLine: 5,
    currentLevel: 1
)

var gameConfig = GameConfig(
    frame: boardFrame,
    itemTopLeft: CGPoint(x: 50, y:boardFrame.maxY - 50),
    itemSize: basicSize,
    itemSpacing: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10),
    circleSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20),
    circlePosition: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20),
    backgroundColor: UIColor.lightGray,
    itemsPerLine: 5,
    currentLevel: 1
)


// Run Game

var scene = GameScene(gameConfig: gameConfig)

let view = SKView(frame: boardFrame)
view.presentScene(scene)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: if you like my answer please mark it as accepted when you click on the gray checkmark on the left side

Comment: the posted code you can just place in the playground it should work out of the box

Comment: what kind of tutorial you need? many tutorials are on raywenderlich page or on medium. just google for the keyword you need to solved :)